# Row and Column merging

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I have a table and I would like to merge some cells in the middle of it, I have tried to look for several ways to do it but don't find any satisfactory solution.

Below I leave an example of the output searched and a MWE with what I have tried, all in all I would like to merge all of the cells with the same sentences.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}  % Always compile at least twice.
\usepackage{
    multicol,           % Use Multi-columns
    multirow,           % Use Multi-rows
    array,
    tabularx
}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% -------------------
% Content
% -------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
   {
    >{\columncolor[HTML]{FFCC67}\bfseries\raggedright}p{3.4cm}
    *{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
   }
\rowcolor[HTML]{CD9934} \multicolumn{4}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}{Unidades Públicas}
\\
\hline \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}  \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}{Empresas no financieras}
& \cellcolor{white} Empresas Públicas
& \cellcolor{white} Sector Público
\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67} Empresas Financieras Monetarias
& \cellcolor{white} \multirow{2}{*}{Instituciones Financieras Públicas}
& \cellcolor{white} Empresas Publicas
& \cellcolor{white} Sector Público
\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67} Empresas Financieras de Monetarias
& \cellcolor{white}\multirow{2}{*}{}
& \cellcolor{white} Empresas Publicas
& \cellcolor{white} Sector Público
\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}{Administraciones públicas}
& \cellcolor{white} Sector Público
\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}{$\neq$}
& \cellcolor{white} Sector Público
\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}{$\neq$}
& \cellcolor{white} Sector Público
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is not compilable since `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` is missing.

Comment: Could you please also add a sketch of the desired output?

Comment: The `+\arrayrulewidth` adjustment factors should be omitted, since there are no vertical rules in the table that would call for this type of adjustment.

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of the texts in the `\multicolumn` commands actually needs a linebreak. Thus a simple `l` type column should be sufficient for all of them.

Comment: Regarding: `multicol,           % Use Multi-columns`: Please be aware that the `\multicolumn` command (to merge cells in a table) can be used without any additional packages. The `multicol` packge on the other hand is not at all related to tables but offers an environment that can typeset text in multiple columns.

Comment: @leandriis sorry, I have modified the code and include an example of what I am after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `nicematrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{FFCC67}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,
                    code-before ={\rectanglecolor{myyellow}{1-1}{1-4}
                                  \rectanglecolor{myyellow!50!white}{2-1}{2-2}
                                  \rectanglecolor{myyellow!50!white}{3-1}{3-1}
                                  \rectanglecolor{myyellow!50!white}{4-1}{4-1}
                                  \rectanglecolor{myyellow!50!white}{5-1}{5-3}
                                  \rectanglecolor{myyellow!50!white}{6-1}{6-3}
                                  \rectanglecolor{myyellow!50!white}{7-1}{7-3}}
                    ]{cccc}
\Block{1-4}{\bfseries Unidades Públicas}\\
\Block{1-2}{Empresas no financieras} & & \Block{3-1}{Empresas\\ Públicas} & \Block{6-1}{Sector\\ Público}\\
\Block{1-1}{Empresas de\\ financieras} & \Block{2-1}{Instituciones\\ Financieras\\ Públicas} &\\ 
\Block{1-1}{Entidades\\ de seguros} & \\
\Block{1-3}{\bfseries Administraciones públicas}\\
\Block{1-3}{$\neq$}\\
\Block{1-3}{$\neq$}&\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the result that you show is what I need. However, when I try to complile the table several errors comeup telling me that the environment is unrecognised. Sorry, but I don't know what I am missing. Might be a compatibility problem?

Comment: The `nicematrix` package I used for the table is a quite new package. Probably you should update your distribution.

Comment: I use overleaf, should it be automatically updated? sorry, but I don't know how this thing of distribution works. thanks for your help

Comment: @RubénPérezSanz: Overleaf does not automatically use the most recent version of the packages. Which TexLive version did you select? With TexLeve2020, the `nicematrix` package (although not its most recent version)  should be available.

Comment: I was using the 2019, once I have update this feature the table seems to be all cloutered up, might be because overleaf is not using the last version of ```nicematrix``` as you said. is there a workaround? or should I wait paciently till oveleaf updates the available packages with the most recent versions?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? Note that I've gotten rid of all `\rowcolor` directives and do not load the `multirow` and `multicol` packages. No need to load the `array` package since it's loaded automatically by the `tabularx` package. I've also done away with all explicit cell width calculations as they don't seem to be needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\mycellcolor{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
    >{\columncolor[HTML]{FFCC67}\raggedright}X
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
    l
    l } 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}\color{white}\bfseries Unidades Públicas}
\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\mycellcolor Empresas no financieras}
& Empresas Públicas & Sector Público
\\
Empresas Financieras Monetarias
& Instituciones Financieras Públicas 
& Empresas Publicas & Sector Público
\\
Empresas Financieras de Monetarias
& % a blank cell & Empresas Publicas & Sector Público
\\ 
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\mycellcolor Administraciones públicas} & Sector Público
\\ 
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\mycellcolor $\neq$} & Sector Público
\\  
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\mycellcolor $\neq$} & Sector Público
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But couldn't SE. administrators use the colors  that you have  used a little less intense and not that horrible blue they have put? :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano - I'd say that the site's new, mostly blue color scheme for LaTeX code blocks is a serious improvement over the previous red-green, "it's an over-decorated Christmas tree!" color scheme. :-)

Comment: @Mico sorry I now I have included an example of the output I am after (colors are not that important at this stage)